# Mapear tabla a relación en hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Tengo una tabla datos, otra tabla entidades ambas tienen relación de muchos a muchos que resulta en una tabla llamada entidades_has_datos. El tema es que tengo otra tabla llamada mensajes que está relaciona de muchos a muchos con la tabla entidades_has_datos y no se mapear esa relación. Coloco una imagen de las relaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MAPEO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTIDADES")
public class Entidades {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="ENTIDADES_SEQ", sequenceName="ENTIDADES_SEQ", initialValue=1,  allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ENTIDADES_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID_ENTIDAD", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NOMBRE_ENTIDAD")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "REPETIBLE")
private boolean repetible;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ENTIDADES_HAS_DATOS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTIDADES_ID_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "ID_ENTIDAD"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DATOS_ID_DATO", referencedColumnName = "ID_DATO"))
//@JsonManagedReference("entidades-datos")
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Datos.class) 
//@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,property="@id", scope = Datos.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("entidades")
private Set<Datos> datos;

@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "entidades", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("entidades")
private Set<Servicios> servicios;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public boolean isRepetible() {
    return repetible;
}

public void setRepetible(boolean repetible) {
    this.repetible = repetible;
}

public Set<Datos> getDatos() {
    return datos;
}

public void setDatos(Set<Datos> datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
}

public Set<Servicios> getServicios() {
    return servicios;
}

public void setServicios(Set<Servicios> servicios) {
    this.servicios = servicios;
}
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "DATOS")
public class Datos {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="DATOS_SEQ", sequenceName="DATOS_SEQ", initialValue=1,  allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DATOS_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID_DATO", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NOMBRE_DATO")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "DESC_DATO")
private String descripcion;

@Column(name = "TIPO_DATO")
private String tipo;

@Column(name = "LARGO_DATO")
private String largo;

@Column(name = "REPETIBLE")
private boolean repetible;

@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "datos", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("datos")
private Set<Entidades> entidades;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getLargo() {
    return largo;
}

public void setLargo(String largo) {
    this.largo = largo;
}

public boolean isRepetible() {
    return repetible;
}

public void setRepetible(boolean repetible) {
    this.repetible = repetible;
}

public Set<Entidades> getEntidades() {
    return entidades;
}

public void setEntidades(Set<Entidades> entidades) {
    this.entidades = entidades;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "MENSAJES")
public class Mensajes {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="MENSAJES_SEQ", sequenceName="MENSAJES_SEQ", initialValue=1,  allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="MENSAJES_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID_MENSAJE", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NOMBRE_MENSAJE")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "CODIGO_MENSAJE")
private String codigo;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SERVICIOS_ID_SERVICIO")
private Servicios servicios;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public Servicios getServicios() {
    return servicios;
}

public void setServicios(Servicios servicios) {
    this.servicios = servicios;
}
}
```

Comment: Ya haz hecho el mapeo para que puedas compartir el código. Si no intenta cuando usas ejb para hacerlo lo hace automáticamente.

Comment: edito la pregunta para colocar el mapeo

Comment: Lo hice utilizando la guía que encontré en la siguiente página:
[Guía de mapeo de relación muchos a muchos con clave compuesta](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) La idea es crear una clase embebida con la clave compuesta en la relación muchos a muchos entre datos y entidades, luego asociar mensajes con la entidad padre de la relación muchos a muchos entre dato y entidades (sea la que se haya elegido). Saludos!